# How do I make an object stick to another like a plaster?

Tags: mesh, shrinkwrap

My goal is to:

- take a 2-D shape
- give it some thickness so it becomes 3-D
- make it adhere (like a plaster, a band-aid or a sticker) to another shape

So far I've managed to thicken the shape with the solidify modifier, but using the shrinkwrap modifier to make it stick to a sphere failed.

See picture of what I managed so far:
[image]

and shriwnkwrap parameters:

[image]

What am I doing wrong that this does not work?

Comment: does your 2D object has enough topology to be bent?

Comment: @moonboots - hmm... I suspect not. How does one make that happen?

Comment: you need to create inner topology so that your object will be able to bend, otherwise it will stay flat, for example try to create some edge loops with the knife tool (K to activate)